# Removing "Series" label on highcahrt-columnrange chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

As you see in the attachment. I want to take off "Series 4"  from the tooltip

My xAxis displays the date and yAxis  displays the difference between `end_time and start_time`

But I  don't know where that "Series 4" comes from.

additional code :

```
                 var series = [];
                $.each(tasks.reverse(), function (i, task) {
                    var item = {
                        name: task.name,
                        data: []
                    };
                    $.each(task.intervals, function (j, interval) {
                        item.data.push({
                            x: interval.from,
                            y: i,
                            label: interval.label,
                            from: interval.from,
                            to: interval.to

                        });



                    });

                    series.push(item);
```

Any help appreciate?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Series 4" comes because you did not specify a name for your series. Usually it's a better idea to give a meaningful name than removing it. Otherwise it could be confusing which data is the tooltip for.

For example:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
}, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I just edited my question I added a code where I retrieve data and push it in series . I tried to add name:'test' but didn't work

Comment: @user2407340 Interesting... This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MVgB4/) works. Can you dump the series object, or create a plunker/jsfiddle to repro your issue?

Comment: I resolved the issue .I forgot to include name in task variable.MY BAD Thanks